# How to pass a posted file to a webmethod in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I have a jQuery pop-up window with a file upload control. On clicking the submit button the posted file has to be passed to a web method (ASP.NET). Please guide me on this.

Comment: so, are you try something? can you provide your code?

Comment: i know how to upload  file in asp.net c#, but how  to do  by using the  JQuery ajax and webmethod.

Comment: possibly duplicate [how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)